# How to Insert Boxable Table Between Prexisting Header and Footer of PDF File

Tags: pdfbox, boxable

In Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, I have created a PDF document with a header and footer.  I'm using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org) and [Boxable](http://dhorions.github.io/boxable/) to put a table between the header and footer.  This works on the first page of the document.  But, when my Boxable table spans several pages, the header and footer only appear on the first page.  They are absent from the second page, third page, etc.

I'm using this `PageContentStream` constructor:

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, true);
```

Below is how I'm loading the template file and creating the table.  Thanks!

```
File pdfFile = pdfUtil.getPdfFile("pdf/table.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
PDPage page = document.getPage(0);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false, true);

// Some code here to set variables

BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yPosition, yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, document, page, true, drawContent);
```